# What is the significance of the color blue in "I Know Who Killed Me"?

Tags: plot-explanation, i-know-who-killed-me

I watched the movie [I Know Who Killed Me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Know_Who_Killed_Me) and I didn't understand the significance of the color blue in the movie. It shows the blue flowers all the time and even killer use all blue weapons for killing, even victims house decoration is mostly blue. Movie poster have blue color flower on it. Most of the things are of same blue shade used in hospitals.

Even in the Aubrey Fleming house many things are of blue color even the cat's collar is blue.

[image: Cat with Blue Collar]

What is the significance of the color blue. Maybe due to some censorship issue when telecasting the movie in India few scenes got cut, I didn't got the point behind it. Even some cutting of scenes have been noticed by me.

Anybody have any clue about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Aubrey & Dakota] <sup>[[Source](http://awesomebadtv.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/i-know-who-killed-me-2007/)]</sup>

From [**TV Tropes**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/IKnowWhoKilledMe?from=Main.IKnowWhoKilledMe):

> **Aubrey's world is blue, Dakota's world is red.**

From [**Not Coming to a Theater Near You**](http://notcoming.com/reviews/iknowwhokilledme/):

> **Aubrey, the good girl, is always blue**. Blue filters, blue clothing, blue roses, blue uniforms for the high school football teams—right down to the blue gag the villain eventually uses on her.
>
> **Dakota, the bad girl, is always red**: red filters, red stripper outfits, red lipstick.

Answer (score 0):

The color blue can represent loyalty and trust, two qualities that are really important to the piano teacher. The reason he abducted Jennifer and Aubrey was to punish them for quitting piano lessons. This is just my guess, but I think the color blue has more to do with the killer than the twins.